# CoreData: Inverse relationships causing crash on save

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a bit of code in my application that generates a Core Data Model and populates it with a set of `NSEntityDescription`s.  Each of these entity descriptions then have an arbitrary number of `NSPropertyDescription`s allocated for them.  These properties are a combination of `NSAttributeDescription`s and `NSRelationshipDescription`s.  All relationships are matched with an existing relationship and they are set as inverse of one another using `setInverseRelationship:`.

The attribute properties work fine, and to-many relationships work fine;  I have tested that thoroughly.  The issue seems to be with `NSRelationshipDescription`s that have a `maxCount` value of 1, meaning the property description returns a `isToMany` value of `NO`.  When the `inverseRelationship` property is set for these type of relationship, Core Data crashes when I try to save any object that utilizes that relationship with the error:

```
2013-11-09 11:17:15.068 Directory[1344:5c03] -[NSManagedObject count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9643820
2013-11-09 11:17:15.074 Directory[1344:5c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9643820'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f9f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01d228b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0203c903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01f8f90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01f8f4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreData                            0x0083c128 -[NSSQLCore _knownOrderKeyForObject:from:inverseToMany:] + 200
    6   CoreData                            0x00773080 -[NSSQLCore _populateRowForOp:withObject:] + 1120
    7   CoreData                            0x00789157 -[NSSQLCore recordValuesForInsertedObject:] + 71
    8   CoreData                            0x00771e8d -[NSSQLCore recordChangesInContext:] + 685
    9   CoreData                            0x00770c55 -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] + 565
    10  CoreData                            0x0073d88c -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 412
    11  CoreData                            0x0073d380 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 4704
    12  CoreData                            0x00769ffc -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 764
    13  Directory                           0x0002f2bf -[ETDatabaseController save] + 111
    14  Directory                           0x0002ba9c -[ETDataLoader performImportWithData:] + 10284
```

The insinuation I am gathering from this is it is considering the inverse relationship to be a to-many relationship when that is not the case. According to my assertions, what I know about each of my relationships is:

```
relationDescription.inverseRelationship != nil
[relationDescription.inverseRelationship.inverseRelationship isEqual:relationDescription]
```

I have tested this by creating the model and populating it with a small set of sample data. Currently, objects that have any sort of attributes, to-many relationships (with/without inverse), and to-one relationship (without inverse) work consistently.  The issues comes when I try to have a to-one relationship with an inverse relationship.

This seems a bit convoluted so let me know if I need to clarify anything better.  Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

The relationship creation is done in two steps, first it creates all the relationships, then it establishes the inverse of each relationship by using a lookup.

```
NSRelationshipDescription *description = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
[description setName:self.name];
[description setDestinationEntity:entity];
[description setMaxCount:(isToMany ?  0 : 1)];
[description setMinCount:0];
[description setOrdered:YES]; // See you in a minute
```

*later...*

```
NSEntityDescription *inverseEntity = newRelationship.destinationEntity;
NSRelationshipDescription *inverseRelationDescription = [inverseEntity relationshipsByName][inverse.name];

if (inverseRelationDescription) {
    inverseRelationDescription.inverseRelationship = newRelationship;
    newRelationship.inverseRelationship = inverseRelationDescription;
} else if ([inverse.name isEqualToString:relation.name]) {
    newRelationship.inverseRelationship = newRelationship;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the model? Perhaps reduced to a minimal example exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I guess writing Edit 1 made something click.  So from what it looks like, if you call `setOrdered:` on a `NSRelationDescription` that is meant to be a to-one relationship, the internals of Core Data automatically considers it a to-many relationship, despite the conflict with the `maxCount` being one.

I fixed this by changing the creation code for the relationship from:

```
NSRelationshipDescription *description = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
[description setName:self.name];
[description setDestinationEntity:entity];
[description setMaxCount:(isToMany ?  0 : 1)];
[description setMinCount:0];
[description setOrdered:YES];
```

to:

```
NSRelationshipDescription *description = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
[description setName:self.name];
[description setDestinationEntity:entity];
[description setMaxCount:(isToMany ?  0 : 1)];
[description setMinCount:0];

if (isToMany)
    [description setOrdered:YES];
```

Comment: Damn, thanks!  That saved me a lot of headache.  Seems the same is true if you're using the Model editor in Xcode as well.  If you switch to many, uncheck the Ordered flag, then switch back, it fixes this error.